# NameError: name 'predict_from_url' is not defined

Tags: python-3.4, raspberry-pi3, mxnet

I am trying an MXNet tutorial mentioned at http://mxnet.io/tutorials/embedded/wine_detector.html (Section "Running the Model" on a raspberry pi3 using python3.4, specifically the script "inception_predict.py". I managed to fix a couple of issue but am getting stumped at this error:

> >> import inception_predict
>   [23:43:37] src/nnvm/legacy_json_util.cc:190: Loading symbol saved by previous version v0.8.0. Attempting to upgrade...
>   [23:43:37] src/nnvm/legacy_json_util.cc:198: Symbol successfully upgraded!
>
> >> predict_from_url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcX0e.jpg")
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "", line 1, in 
>   NameError: name 'predict_from_url' is not defined

Function predict_from_url is defined in the imported file inception_predict.py (as mentioned in the tutorial) so why is python telling me it is not defined?
 What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial has a few errors that you need to fix to make it run:

- add time to the import list in the inception_predict.py

  ... 
  import cv2, os, urllib, **time**
  ...
- use a URL that you can actually download directly (use your favorite image search engine to find ones)
- call the full name function

  **inception_predict.** predict_from_url("https://media.mnn.com/assets/images/2017/01/cow-in-pasture.jpg.838x0_q80.jpg")

After these small changes you will see something like this:

```
pre-processed image in 0.27312707901
MKL Build:20170209
forward pass in 0.131096124649
probability=0.784963, class=n02403003 ox
probability=0.099463, class=n03868242 oxcart
probability=0.035585, class=n03967562 plow, plough
probability=0.033620, class=n02415577 bighorn, bighorn sheep, cimarron, Rocky Mountain bighorn, Rocky Mountain sheep, Ovis canadensis
probability=0.015443, class=n02412080 ram, tup
[(0.78496253, 'n02403003 ox'), (0.09946309, 'n03868242 oxcart'), (0.035584591, 'n03967562 plow, plough'), (0.033620458, 'n02415577 bighorn, bighorn sheep, cimarron, Rocky Mountain bighorn, Rocky Mountain sheep, Ovis canadensis'), (0.015442736, 'n02412080 ram, tup')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Guy. Yes, a number of issues in the tutorial. It didn't occur to me to use the full name function call. That would have revealed the other issues.